# Can I use Direct Path Loads in Oracle Instant Client?

Tags: sql, oracle, instantclient

I have used SQL*LOADER in Oracle full client for bulk upload using ctl files. But I am planning to move to instant client in which SQL*LOADER doesn't work. I found from the Oracle OCI reference http://oracle.su/docs/11g/appdev.112/e10646/oci13obn.htm#BAJJGACH that I can use Direct Path Loads in OCI. Does this mean, that I will be able to use Direct Path Loads using Oracle Instant Client? Can you point me how some good links\tutorials how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle instant client does not contain sql*loader. Some people manage to get it working by copying sqlldr executable into the instant client directory as sqlldr does not rely on any server side component. The question is : is it worth the trouble? And of course: it's not supported by Oracle.

Check out this thread:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=460097

Comment: Thanks but I've searched a lot of forums but all say "SQL*LOADER" doesnt work with Instant Client. I need to know about Direct Path API in Instant client and how to use it for bulk upload from files.